# How can I use Class View for a web page code behind in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I've always just used incremental search, but have recently starting using a class browser plugin for vim and would like something of the same in Visual Studio to navigate methods, properties, etc. in a browser type window.  Seems like this is what Class View is for, but when I'm on a page's code behind, it doesn't show up on the class view window.  When I search for the class, it shows up but when I click on it I get "The definition of the object is hidden.".  Is there some basic setup thing I'm doing wrong or does VS not support class view for page classes?  Is there an extension that does this (I'm using VS2010)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you're looking for?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx

Comment: Interesting.  It is exactly what I'm looking for, but I get 'Unable to get code items' when I expand it.